# Who is in PR_SENT_REPRESENTING

Tags: outlook

In outlook, you have the opportunity to set values PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_EMAIL_ADDRESS, and PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_NAME. This happens when someone is able to message on behalf of a client. 
I've been reading all the MSDN pages, outlook help etc but cant seem to work out who is actually in these values.

In the scenario A sends an email on the behalf of B, whos name and email address would be in these values?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you looked at these properties with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button) or MFCMAPI?